# Constraint annotations are not visible

Tags: hibernate, maven, validation

I'm working on a project and I need to validate a Java bean with using Hibernate Validator in my code. I created an API for processing some data and I want to encapsulate it into a jar library and then add it as a dependency into a separate web project.
The problem is when I add either `@NotEmpty` or `@NotBlank` annotations into my Java bean the validator doesn't see those annotations when I try to use the entity inside another project. Neither reflection API can find those annotations at runtime. Here is an example:

```
@Entry(...)
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @NotBlank
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    @NotBlank
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

I'm using Spring LDAP API so don't pay attention to @Entry annotation for now.
This code then becomes a jar file via Maven install process and is available in local Maven repository.
The unit test inside the project works perfectly showing two violations as follows:

```
public class PersonValidationTest {
    @Test
    public void testValidation() {
       ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
       Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

       Person person = new Person();

       Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> violations = validator.validate(person);
       assertThat(violations).hasSize(2);
    }
}
```

Next I try to use the Person class (which is my Java bean) within another project inside Spring MVC controller like this:

```
@RestController
public class PersonController
    private Validator validator;

    @Autowired
    public void setValidator(Validator validator) {
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/api/person")
    public ResponseEntity<String> createPerson(@RequestBody String data) {
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject();

        Person p = new Person();
        try {
           //person = PersonUtils.json2Person(data);

           Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> violations = validator.validate(p);   

            if(violations.isEmpty()) {
                response.put("status", "success");
                response.put("data", new JSONObject(p.toJSON()));
            } else {
                JSONArray errors = new JSONArray();
                for(ConstraintViolation<Person> v : violations) {
                    JSONObject err = new JSONObject();
                    errObj.put(v.getPropertyPath().toString(), v.getMessage());
                    errors.put(err);
                }
                response.put("status", "failed");
                response.put("data", errors);
            }
          } catch (Exception e) {
              response.put("status", "error");
              response.put("message", e.getMessage());
          }
      return new ResponseEntity<>(response.toString(), HttpStatus.OK)
   }
}
```

The Hibernate Validator is created inside configuration class and then injected by Spring framework but it's not important here so I will not provide the code. The issue is that Person class's getters missing those `@NotBlank` constraint annotations when validation is being done inside the controller's method. Neither looping through `p.getClass().getMethods()` and then through `method.getAnnotations()` shows any traces of those annotations. The validation method simply returns empty list of violations like there are no any constraint annotations existent. I wonder how it might be possible that after compiling the Java bean into a jar and adding the jar as dependency in another Maven project the annotations become unavailable when they should be. I tried to mark the project with Person class as a dependency directly in IDE (Eclipse STS) and in that case the validation works as expected showing two constraint violations but when Maven dependency is used instead the validation doesn't work. Is there something I do wrong in terms of using the annotations inside Maven projects? I tried to research and Googled like crazy but no luck. There is no info about such problem anywhere like the case is very unique and nobody had this issue before. I know that there is Spring's validation with @Valid annotation is handy and can be at use in this scenario but I hid some specifics of Person class and I can't use it for implicit marshaling from JSON to Java object. I have to get JSON as a String and then convert it into Person via Jackson API using custom mapping of fields. After that I run validation to check if all data is present. So the main issue is the mysterious disappearing of the `@NotBlank` annotation. I need help to find out what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How exactly did you create the JAR which you then used as a dependency in the other project? Which Maven commands exactly did you execute?

Comment: I use Eclipse Oxigen for my non-Spring project. The Maven is embedded into the IDE and I simply run "Run as -> Maven Install" command from the right click menu on pom.xml. That's suits me well enough. I don't think there is something irregular happens in that case but I'll check other options, i.e. command line etc.

Comment: I'm closing this thread since I found work around of the issue. Instead of using Hibernate Validator on the entity I created DTO class PersonDTO and put constraint annotation on required fields. When controller handles a request the data automatically validated with @Valid annotation against DTO object which is populated from JSON data by Spring itself. After that I simply use ModelMapper to convert DTO to Person entity. This way I don't need to validate Person entity anymore so the problem has gone.